# Numpy where condition when met must modify the original value, if not original value must remain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
Policy_id Value 
     A           xyz
     B           abc
     A           pqr
     C           lmn
```

And I want to use `np.where()` such that whenever the `policy_id` is equal to `A` the corresponding value must be appended with a `*`.

```
Policy_id    Value 
     A           xyz*
     B           abc
     A           pqr*
     C           lmn
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['Policy_id'].eq('A'),df['Value']+'*',df['Value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your dataframe in place and use `np.where`:

```
df['Value'] += np.where(df['Policy_id'].eq('A'), '*', '')
```

output:

```
  Policy_id Value
0         A  xyz*
1         B   abc
2         A  pqr*
3         C   lmn
```